# How to split a string of integers into a list of integers where the string of integers are split up into ascending numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Working on a homework question where it asks to take any given string of integers between 0 and 9, and split that in to a ascending list. For example, given a string of integers like `'455666777788888999999'`, I would like it to return `[4, 5, 56, 66, 77, 778, 888, 899, 999]` or given a string of integers like `'045349'` I would like it to return a list like `[0, 4, 5, 34]`. The next integer only has to be strictly larger than the previous integer. any integers that are not large enough to keep adding to the list of growing integers should be discarded.

I know that with list comprehension, I can convert a string into a list of integers with something like this: `[int(x) for x in '455666777788888999999']`, but this breaks down every element in the string into indivisual elements in a list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you supposed to split up the inputted string if there are no markers in the string for where the splits should be? I.e. '999' can be '9', '9', '9' or '99', '9' or '999' etc.

Comment: Are there more constraints? For example `[4,5666777788888999999]` seems to fit the requirement of splitting into ascending numbers? It seems like there should be a requirement that it is split into the most numbers or the smallest numbers, etc...

Comment: @ShaunLowis the next integer in the list has to be larger than the previous integer. the number '999' would be returned as [9,99].

Comment: @MarkMeyer the next integer only has to be strictly larger than the previous number . so in the string case '45666777788888999999' would return [4,5,6,66,67.......]

Comment: So if the next integer has to be larger than the one prior you can split the integers incrementally having the first integer as a single integer the next as a 2 digit integer if its lesser than the prior and so on ...

Comment: @CalebNjiiri only issue with that is if the next integer is a single digit integer that is already larger than the one before it, it would not make sense to have a 2 digit number. for example '1234' would be broken up into [1,2,3,4] instead of [1,23]

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm afraid this might be off-topic for stackoverflow

Comment: @PaulLo like i said I know that a list comprehension like [int(x) for x in '455666777788888999999'] would work but it would split every single element in the string to a list of integers with no regard wether to wether the next element is increasing or not.

Comment: OP has clearly shown the requirements for the algorithm and made an attempt. This is on-topic and should be re-opened. For folks that aren't understanding the requirements, Mark's split doesn't work because the next increasing number in the optimal split (greedy) is `[4, 5...]`.

Comment: Got you, ggorlen. I didn't see much of code in the question, but understand piethon's attempt to learn. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reduce/accumulation operation so a list comp isn't terribly appropriate.

Here's a naive algorithm: keep a running accumulator of digits. Whenever the current total is greater than the tail of the result list or the result list is empty, append the accumulator to the result list and empty the accumulator.

```
digits = "455666777788888999999"
res = []
accum = ""

for e in digits:
    accum += e

    if not res or int(accum) > res[-1]:
        res.append(int(accum))
        accum = ""

print(res) # => [4, 5, 56, 66, 77, 778, 888, 899, 999]
```

Comment: You're missing a 9 at the end

Comment: I don't follow. Can you clarify what you mean? OP's requirements state "any integers that are not large enough to keep adding to the list of growing integers should be discarded."

Comment: Your input string has six 9s. There's only 5 in your list

Comment: Yes, this is intentional. Did you see OP's requirements and example and my above comment?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be. It's not the next larger number after 899, 999 is. OP is asking for a greedy algorithm: take the smallest number possible that's greater than the previous element which we can make using the remainder of the list and discard anything left over.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't exaust the remaining numbers... 9999 is definitely larger than 899

Comment: Yes, but OP wants _the smallest number possible after each given number_. Why? This just happens to be what OP asked for and how the algorithm works. You're not alone: others in the thread above seem confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing came to my mind was to use recursion. Construct a helper function which takes a minimum value to compare with, the string to split and the result array. Read the string from the beginning until you find a value larger than the minimum value, then pass this number as minimum and the string without this number for the next recursive call. Or you can keep the string static and pass the index you're at instead.

The code would be something like:

```
void helper(minimum, int_string, result_arr):
    for i in range(1, len(int_string)):
        num = int(string[0:i])
        if num > minimum:
            result_arr.append(num)
            helper(num, string[i:], result_arr)
```

You may want to handle some edge cases based on the problem given, like if the last bit of the string is less than the second last number or if the given string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```py
    def asc_split(s):
        r = [int(s[0])]
        s=s[1:]
        while int(s)>r[-1]:
            i=1
            while int(s[:i])<=r[-1]:i+=1
            r+=[int(s[:i])]
            s=s[i:]
        return r
```